# python list to newline separated value

Tags: jquery, python, pylons

Im trying to get data in pylon to use in jquery autocomplete, 
 the librarary i'm using for autocomplete it requires this format

```
abc
pqr
xyz
```

and in python i have data in this format

```
[["abc"], ["pqr"],["xyz"]
```

How do i convert this list to the above one.

Edit:
  I trying to use these for a autocompete and i'm using pylons, in which the query to the server return list in this format

```
    [["abc"], ["pqr"],["xyz"]
```

http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/ this library except remote call in

```
abc 
pqr
xyz
```

i tried to use

```
"\n".join(item[0] for item in my_list)
```

but it returns data in firebug like this.

```
'asd\ndad\nweq'
```

i want it to be in

```
abc
pqr
xyz
```

any help would be appreciated as i'm a PHP developer this is first time i'm trying to do code in python.

thnaks

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON?

Comment: `\n` *is* a carriage return, so you're getting exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 13):

```
"\n".join(item[0] for item in my_list)
```

However, what's this got to do with JSON...?

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure what you want, but you may try:

```
nested_list = [ ["abc"], ["pqr"], ["xyz"] ]
data = "\n".join( (item[0] for item in nested_list) )
```

This will convert your list of lists into a string separated by newline characters.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is doing what you want it to, but I imagine you're inspecting the results in the python REPL or ipython, and expecting to see new lines instead of '\n'.

```
In [1]: items = [["abc"], ["pqr"],["xyz"]]
In [2]: s = "\n".join(item[0] for item in items)
In [3]: s
Out[3]: 'abc\npqr\nxyz'
In [4]: print s
abc
pqr
xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

Er I'm not sure what exactly you want, but if you need to print that you could do

```
for l in data:
    print l[0]
```

or if you want to make it a flat list, you could do something like

```
map(lambda x: x[0], a)
```

or if you even just want a single string with newlines, you could do something like

```
"\n".join(map(lambda x: x[0], a))
```

Dunno if that helped at all, but wish you luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this, though it's hard to know based on your description:

```
  >>> l = [["abc"],["pqr"],["xyz"]]
  >>> "".join(map(lambda a:a[0] + "\n",l))
  'abc\npqr\nxyz\n'
```