# Create lines of text, '\n'.join(my_list) is missing trailing newline

Tags: string, python-2.7, newline

I want to join N strings together, one line for each item:

```
my_list=['one', 'two', 'three']
lines='\n'.join(my_list)
```

Unfortunately I need a trailing newline at the end of each line in `lines`. In the above solution the last line is missing the newline.

... I use Python 2.7

Answer (score 6):

Just add another `\n` like this(since the output of `join()` is also a string):

```
my_list=['one', 'two', 'three']
print '\n'.join(my_list)+'\n'
```

Answer (score 5):

In Python 3.6, you may also use generator expression ([PEP289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)):

```
''.join(f"{row}\n" for row in my_list)
```

It's a bit cleaner to me.

Comment: It's not generator expressions that is new to python 3.6 but fstrings. See [PEP 498](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to manually adding to the return value of join, you could (manually as well) append the empty string to your list.

```
>>> my_list=['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> my_list.append('')
>>> '\n'.join(my_list)
'one\ntwo\nthree\n'
```

Comment: There's no real reason to do this. It looks more efficient than `'\n'.join(my_list)+'\n'`, but due to how python cheats when an immutable object only has one reference, it's usually less efficient. The append way is about 25% slower on my machine *and*, it's not as obvious why the `''` is added compared to the `'\n'`.

Comment: @Dunes Couldn't find evidence of that in the python source code. Could you point me to it? Thanks!

Comment: @Bharel You can see direct evidence of this by doing `s= b'some-non-constant-string'.decode(); s = s + 'some string'`. Compare the value of `id(s)` before and after and note they are the same. If you initialised `s` with a string literal then the ids would be different. The implementation is across a parts of the code. The first place is `Objects/unicodeobject.c:PyUnicode_append` and `unicode_modifiable`. And the second is `Python/ceval.c:unicode_concatenate`, which is called if `s = s + t` or `s += t` is called. Without this the condition in `PyUnicode_Append` would never trigger.

Comment: @Dunes amazing. Thank you very much! I was actually looking at PyUnicode_Concat and didn't realize there was another unicode concatenate. (Wondered who calls Append too)

Comment: PyUnicode_Concat is the implementation of `str.__add__`. If you subclass-ed `str`, this is what would get called when you added your subclass instances together. PyUnicode_Append is the interpreter's micro-optimisation if it detects both operands to `+` have type `str`.

Comment: @Dunes Should this be considered part of Python's promised behavior or an implementation detail of CPython?

Answer (score 0):

Using print before, it works:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(ls)
one
two
three
>>>
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) for details on the difference on strings and string representation like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560863/python-join-with-newline).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790805/python-list-to-newline-separated-value) as well, you can find a solution.

Comment: Sorry, I need a string. The `print()` does not help.

Comment: @guettli: I need to read more thoroughly :) Does adding '\n' help you like mentioned above?

Comment: Ok, that's all I wanted to know. so this is what actually did what you wanted.