# Make a list of strings into a string with each value on a new line

Tags: python

So, I have a project in which I have a list of strings:

```
outputs = ['cow', 'chicken', 'pig']
```

I need to turn them into a string, with each value separated by a newline, like so:

```
cow
chicken
pig
```

I found a solution at [python list to newline separated value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790805/python-list-to-newline-separated-value), but it uses a list like this:

```
outputs = [['cow'], ['chicken'], ['pig']]
```

and whenever I run:

```
 answer = "\n".join(map(lambda x: x[0], outputs))
 print(answer)
```

It returns `'c'`, as is the case with all the other answers in that question.

Comment: Did you try `"\n".join(outputs)`?

Comment: Oops, could not find that article you marked as duplicate. Sorry for using your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can join a list of strings by another string by simply using:

```
str = "\n".join(outputs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when you did:

```
map(lambda x: x[0], outputs)
```

You created an iterable consisting of the first letter of each element in `outputs`:

```
>>> outputs = ['cow', 'chicken', 'pig']
>>> list(map(lambda x: x[0], outputs))
['c', 'c', 'p']
```

Your over-thinking this. In this case, you don't even need to use `map`. You can simply use `str.join`:

```
'\n'.join(outputs)
```