# Convert list to multiline string without print

Tags: python, string

In the code

```
list1=['my data items1', 'my data items2','my data items3']
```

When I do

```
str1=''
for i in list1:
    str1=str1+i+'\n'
```

I get `str1='my data items1\nmy data items2\nmy data items3'`

I want `str1` to be a multiline string but it seems there is no way to do that without using `print` statement or is there a way?

I expected a multiline string but not getting one without using print.
I need to send this list as email body so need a variable assigned to a string variable.

Comment: Where is this "multiline" string going to be used? What does "_without print_" mean? Saying "multiline" usually means you need to _show or display_ the string _somewhere_, so typical examples add a `\n` then print it out to the console or write it to a file.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [Make a list of strings into a string with each value on a new line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45982879/2745495), but just not `print`-ing out the resulting string.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4601716/2681662

Comment: I need to send it as an email body so using print is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use string `join()` here:

```py
list1 = ['my data items1', 'my data items2','my data items3']
output = "\n".join(list1)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
my data items1
my data items2
my data items3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list1 = ['my data items1', 'my data items2', 'my data items3']
str1 = ""
for i in list1:
    str1 += i + '\n'

multiline_str = str1

print(multiline_str)
```